# Unable to connect to nx app running inside docker container

Tags: docker, nx.dev

I am unable to open the app from browser.
Running the following command inside docker:

`nx serve --port 80`

Docker is started with following command:

`docker run -p 80:80 -d <my_nx_app_image>`

I am able to get the index.html from terminal (inside running docker container)

`wget http://localhost:80`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps:

- Open **project.json** file of your nx app.
- Find the key "serve" and search for parameter "configuration" under it.
- Add a param with name "**hostname**" with value **0.0.0.0**

Example:

```
"production": {
      "buildTarget": "<your_nx_app>:build:production",
      "dev": false,
      "hostname": "0.0.0.0"
    }
```

Note:
By default nx daemon does not allow remote connections on ports below 1024 by default.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here we are. I finally found a solution that helped me. Thanks to manojadams and [Docker-compose, Nx, Angular error "localhost didn’t send any data."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75496329/docker-compose-nx-angular-error-localhost-didn-t-send-any-data). It helped me to dig in the right way

```
FROM node:16.15.0-alpine3.15

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN [ "npm", "install" ]
COPY . .

EXPOSE 4200

CMD [ "npx", "nx", "serve", "vaccine", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

And related docker commands:

```
docker build -t my_app:dev .
docker run -d --rm --name my_app-1 -p 4200:4200 my_app:dev
```